# how is disk space allocated after we assign space in Files/Filegroups for a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

if we say that for a file/filegroup with restricted growth to 10,240MB (10GB) and the 'initial size' is say 5120MB (5GB), then how is this space used on the Disk drive where this database sits.

What i mean is that, whether 5GB of space will be used on the disk or will it reserve and show 10GB of space being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will use 5Gb of space and grow the file as needed.  When it gets to 10Gb your database will die horribly until you give it more space.

Answer (score 1):

The initial size of the database file (whether it's a data file or a transaction log file) is going to be the hard disk space that SQL Server allocates from the start.

It will grow depending on what you have set for growth, and even if the transaction log is backed up (truncating the t-log) or data is removed from the data file it will not implicitly shrink.  It will remain the same size unless a `SHRINKFILE` is called against it.